# Write permissions on a folder or UNC path in c#

Tags: c#, directory, file-permissions, unc

Any way to check if write permissions are available on a given path that could be either a local folder (c:\temp) or a UNC (\server\share)?  I can't use try/catch because I might have write permissions but not delete so I wouldn't be able to delete created file...

Comment: Permissions can change during the time that your application is running. Or the network could go down after write but before delete. You have to work out how to deal with those situations *anyway* - why write more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the [`FileIOPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) class and the [`FileIOPermissionAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess.aspx) enum.

`FileIOPermissionAccess.Write`:

> Access to write to or delete a file or directory. Write access includes deleting and overwriting files or directories.

---

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, myPath);

try
{
   f.Demand();
   //permission to write/delete/overwrite
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
   //there is no permission to write/delete/overwrite
}
```

Comment: Any new updates for the solution possible? This code does not work in UNC paths

Answer (score 3):

You use a *permissions demand*, thus:

```
FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "C:\\test_r");
f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "C:\\example\\out.txt");
try
{
  f2.Demand();
  // do something useful with the file here
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
  // deal with the lack of permissions here.
}
```

specifying the permissions you want and the file system object(s) desired. If you don't have the demanded permission, a Security exception is thrown. More details at

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315529
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx

For a variety of reasons — race conditions being one of them — it's more complicated than it might seem to examine NTFS file system permissions.

Apparently, we figured out a while back that this is a no-op for UNC paths. See this question, [Testing a UNC Path's "Accessability"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732347/testing-a-unc-paths-accessability), for detials.

A little google-fu suggests that this CodeProject class might be of use, though: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14402/Testing-File-Access-Rights-in-NET-2-0

Comment: Neither solution worked for UNC.  I have a UNC path that has Read access but not Write.  If I pass that path to the code above both return positive for Write.

Comment: Yes...apparently, we figured out a couple years ago that that is the case :D -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732347/testing-a-unc-paths-accessability. Looks like you need look at the ACL for it directly. This might work: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14402/Testing-File-Access-Rights-in-NET-2-0. I've amended my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: Appreciate your help but that didn't work either...  I'll have to improvise I guess.